# If dict key doesn't exist or is zero?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like to determine which of the following states a dict key's value is in:

1. Doesn't exist
2. Exists, but is equal to an int of 0
3. Exists, and is equal to an int greater than 0

Here's what I'm currently trying:

```
if item[itemTo] == 0:
    print("You don't have a %s." % (itemTo))
elif item[itemTo] > 0:
    print("You have %i of %s." % (item[itemTo]))
else:
    print("%s doesn't exist." % (itemTo))
```

But, when `itemTo` isn't in the `item` dict, I get this error at the line `if item[itemTo] == 0:`:

```
KeyError: 'whatever_value_of_itemTo'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to change the order of the tests:

```
if itemTo not in item:
    print("%s doesn't exist." % (itemTo))
elif item[itemTo] > 0:
    print("You have %i of %s." % (item[itemTo]))
else:
    print("You don't have a %s." % (itemTo))
```